# How can I make it so that the player loses health when an enemy collides with a different object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kGQS.jpg) an image of what my game looks like so far so that you can get a better idea but I need it so that when one of the outer capsules touches the red box the player (middle capsule) loses health.

I have tried creating a new script which checks for collisions but I couldn't get it to work and am unsure where to go from here. Below is my code for how the health bar works and pressing the space bar reduces health for demonstration purposes.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float MaxHealth;
    public Slider _slide;
    private float currentHealth;

    void Start()
    {
        currentHealth = MaxHealth;
        _slide.maxValue = MaxHealth;
        _slide.value = MaxHealth;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            TakeDamage(25f);

        if(currentHealth <=0)
        {
            //move to game over
        }
    }

    void TakeDamage(float Damage)
    {
        currentHealth = currentHealth - Damage;
        _slide.value = currentHealth;
    }
}
```

At one point I tried using

```
    void Update()
    {
        (collision.collider.name == "Barrier");
            TakeDamage(25f);

        if(currentHealth <=0)
        {
            //move to game over
        }
    }
```

but realised this is completely wrong, as well as trying to add a box collider to the red "barrier" to aid this but it didn't fix anything.

Update 2:
Also tried changing it so that the enemies move towards the barrier and not the player and added the code:

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        TakeDamage(25f);

        if(currentHealth <=0)
        {
            //move to game over
        }
    }
```

which doesn't present any errors but rather just doesn't do anything. The enemy capsules just go through it and to the centre, with no health being lost.

Comment: How does the script look, where you detect the collision between game objects?

Comment: @rootpanthera I haven't really gotten anything yet, I had a few ideas but nothing worked so that's when I resorted to asking here.

Comment: `have tried creating a new script which checks for collisions but I couldn't get it to work and am unsure where to go from here` .. could you show us what you tried and explain what exactly about it didn't behave as expected?

Comment: @derHugo I've added some more things I have tried and something new I tried to the post

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to check for collisions using `OnCollisionEnter3D` and then use the `TakeDamage` function inside of it. Here is an example:

```
public class PlayerHealth: MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter3D(Collision3D col) //Check for collision
    {
        TakeDamage(25f);
    }
}
```

Note that for this function to work, both objects need a 3d collider and a rigid body. If you don't want your character to fall, just set gravity to 0.

Comment: Well not if OP uses 3D Rigidbody and colliders .. the screenshot looks like it

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't realise, just change the collision type to 3d instead